# scala build up string from iterating over map

Tags: scala

if i have a map and want to build up a string from iterating over it, is there a way to have the final string be a result of an expression instead of defining a variable and modifying that inside a loop?

instead of this

```
val myMap = Map("1" -> "2", "3"->"4") 
var s = ""
myMap foreach s += ...
```

i'd rather it be

```
var s = myMap something ...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with a fold:

```
scala> myMap.foldLeft("") { (s: String, pair: (String, String)) =>
     |   s + pair._1 + pair._2
     | }
res0: java.lang.String = 1234
```

Comment: Potentially a lot of expensive string concatenation there if the map reaches a large size.

Comment: That's true. If concatenation is all you're after, use `mkString` as in Daniel's or Kevin's answer.

Answer (score 18):

I'd just `map` and `mkString`. For example:

```
val s = (
    Map("1" -> "2", "3"->"4") 
    map { case (key, value) => "Key: %s\nValue: %s" format (key, value) } 
    mkString ("", "\n", "\n")
)
```

Answer (score 13):

As for Daniel's answer, but with a couple of optimisations and my own formatting preferences:

```
val myMap = Map("1" -> "2", "3"->"4")
val s = myMap.view map {
  case (key, value) => "Key: " + key + "\nValue: " + value
} mkString ("", "\n", "\n")
```

The optimisations:

1. By first creating a `view` of the map, I avoid creating an intermediate collection
2. On profiling, direct String concatenation is faster than `String.format`

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly new to Scala, but you can try `reduceLeft`. It goes accumulating a partial value (the string being joined with every element). For example, if you want the keys (or the values) joined in a string, just do:

```
val s = myMap.keys.reduceLeft( (e, s) =>  e + s)
```

This results in "`13`"

Comment: @Kevin, haha, yes, you're right. I said I was fairly new to Scala :)

Answer (score 2):

This works also fine if you don't bother about your own formatting:

```
scala> Map("1" -> "2", "3"->"4").mkString(", ")
res6: String = 1 -> 2, 3 -> 4
```